# my table is looking weird and cant figure out what i did wrong on the javascript

Tags: javascript, html

so for some reason my table comes out wonky and unfinished looking and off place i cant figure out what i did wrong and i am stuck could someone please help me out
problems the script wont let me edit or save anything also random text box next to add row and total is messed up too[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR4tV.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script>
    function edit_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="block";

 var fforder=document.getElementById("fforder_row"+no);
 var ffaddress=document.getElementById("ffaddress_row"+no);
 var ffstatus=document.getElementById("ffstatus_row"+no);
 var ffdate=document.getElementById("ffdate_row"+no);
  var fftotal=document.getElementById("fftotal_row"+no);

 var fforder_data=fforder.innerHTML;
 var ffaddress_data=ffaddress.innerHTML;
 var ffstatus_data=ffstatus.innerHTML;
 var ffdate_data=ffdate.innerHTML;
  var fftotal_data=fftotal.innerHTML;

 fforder.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='fforder_text"+no+"' value='"+fforder_data+"'>";
 ffaddress.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='ffaddress_text"+no+"' value='"+ffaddress_data+"'>";
 ffstatus.innerHTML="<select id='ffstatus_text"+no+"' value='"+ffstatus_data+"'><option value>-select-</option><option value='FF'>Shipped</option><option value='RF'>Delivered</option><option value='PF'>Canceled</option><option value='DF'>Open</option></select>";
 ffdate.innerHTML="<input type='date' id='ffdate_text"+no+"' value='"+ffdate_data+"'>";
  fftotal.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='fftotal_text"+no+"' value='"+fftotal_data+"'>";
}

function save_row(no)
{
 var fforder_val=document.getElementById("fforder_text"+no).value;
 var ffaddress_val=document.getElementById("ffaddress_text"+no).value;
 var e =document.getElementById("ffstatus_text"+no);
 var ffstatus_val=e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
 var ffdate_val=document.getElementById("ffdate_text"+no).value;
  var fftotal_val=document.getElementById("fftotal_text"+no).value;

 document.getElementById("fforder_row"+no).innerHTML=fforder_val;
 document.getElementById("ffaddress_row"+no).innerHTML=ffaddress_val;
 document.getElementById("ffstatus_row"+no).innerHTML=ffstatus_val;
 document.getElementById("ffdate_row"+no).innerHTML=ffdate_val;
  document.getElementById("fftotal_row"+no).innerHTML=fftotal_val;

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="none";
}

function delete_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";
}

function add_row()
{
 var new_fforder=document.getElementById("new_fforder").value;
 var new_ffaddress=document.getElementById("new_ffaddress").value;
 var new_ffstatus=document.getElementById("new_ffstatus").value;
 var new_ffdate=document.getElementById("new_ffdate").value;
  var new_fftotal=document.getElementById("new_fftotal").value;

 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='fforder_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_fforder+"</td><td id='ffaddress_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_ffaddress+"</td><td id='ffstatus_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_ffstatus+"</td><td id='ffdate_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_ffdate+"</td><td id='fftotal_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_fftotal+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_fforder").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_ffaddress").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_ffstatus").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_ffdate").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_fftotal").value="";
}</script>

</head>
<body>
 <h2>Orders</h2>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
    <tr>
    <th>Order Number</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Order Status</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Total</th>

    </tr>

    <tr id="row1">
    <td id="fforder_row1">#123333</td>
    <td id="ffaddress_row1">38923 Trevors Lane</td>
    <td id="ffstatus_row1">Shipped</td>
    <td id="ffdate_row1">2020-12-21</td>
    <td id="fftotal_row1">10.00</td>
    <td>
    <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('1')">
    <input type="button" id="save_button1" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('1')">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="row2">
    <td id="fforder_row2">#233442</td>
    <td id="ffaddress_row2">39002 Joint Ave</td>
    <td id="ffstatus_row2">Delivered</td>
    <td id="ffdate_row2">2020-12-21</td>
    <td id="fftotal_row2">102.00</td>
    <td>
    <input type="button" id="edit_button2" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('2')">
    <input type="button" id="save_button2" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('2')">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('2')">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="row3">
    <td id="fforder_row3">#990202</td>
    <td id="ffaddress_row3">29783 Marc Jobs NE</td>
    <td id="ffstatus_row3">Open</td>
    <td id="ffdate_row3">2020-12-21</td>
    <td id="fftotal_row3">1,020.00</td>
    <td>
    <input type="button" id="edit_button3" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('3')">
    <input type="button" id="save_button3" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('3')">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('3')">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_fforder"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_ffaddress"></td>
    <td>
    <select name="ffstatus" id="new_ffstatus">
        <option value="">-select-</option>
        <option value="FF">Shipped</option>
        <option value="RF">Delivered</option>
        <option value="PF">Canceled</option>
        <option value="DF">Open</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="date" id="new_ffdate"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_fftotal"></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: look at your error messages.  ffcode is not defined

Comment: i fixed it now thanks but still more problems

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the plugin datatable. Because it is flexible and allows basic operations (add, modify, delete rows).

Comment: Your statement is true, but the performance of these functions is not the best. For this reason, I recommend using the datatable plugin.